# Multiple queries into one query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to combine multiple queries into one. Any one have any ideas?

SELECT In_year, count(In_year) AS Num_Of_Year
FROM INTERNSHIP 
GROUP BY In_year;

SELECT In_qtr, count(In_qtr) AS Num_Of_Qtr
FROM INTERNSHIP
GROUP BY In_Qtr;

SELECT In_location, count(In_location) AS Num_Of_Location
FROM INTERNSHIP
GROUP BY In_location;

If I run each of these queries by themselves, I get what I am looking for in the result.  My problem is I cannot figure out how to combine these 3 queries into 1, I tried to combing them, but ended up getting the wrong output.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the UNION clause and organizing it a bit can do the trick:

```
SELECT 'Year' As Topic, In_year As Value, count(In_year) AS Count 
FROM INTERNSHIP 
GROUP BY In_year

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Qtr' As Topic, In_qtr As Value, count(In_qtr) AS Count 
FROM INTERNSHIP 
GROUP BY In_Qtr

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Location' As Topic, In_location As Value, count(In_location) AS Count
FROM INTERNSHIP 
GROUP BY In_location;
```

That's the only way to show it in a single query, because the three SELECT will have different number of rows, so you can't add the colums in natural form.

Comment: Thanks! I understood your answer the best.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the INTERNSHIP table as a driving list to connect the other "group by" SQLs:

```
select
   t1.In_year, y.Num_Of_Year,
   t1.In_qtr, q.Num_Of_Qtr,
   t1.In_location, l.Num_Of_Location
FROM
  (select distinct In_year, In_qtr, In_location from INTERNSHIP)  t1
   join (SELECT In_year, count(In_year) AS Num_Of_Year FROM INTERNSHIP GROUP BY In_year) y on t1.In_year = y.In_year
   join (SELECT In_qtr, count(In_qtr) AS Num_Of_Qtr FROM INTERNSHIP GROUP BY In_Qtr) q on t1.In_Qtr = q.In_Qtr
   join (SELECT In_location, count(In_location) AS Num_Of_Location FROM INTERNSHIP GROUP BY In_location) l on t1.In_location = l.In_location
```